# C++ return type equals string if one of the parameters is a string

Tags: c++, templates

This function should accept at least 3 types: string, int and double.
It should add lval to rval and return that. The problem is that if one of them is a string it should concatenate the values.

Example: lval = 1, rval = "Bruce", return = "1Bruce"

Example: lval = "Tom", rval = 2, return = "Tom2"

Example: lval = 1, rval = 3.0, return = 4.0

I tried to add a third typename called T and use that as the AddObject type but that just threw unidentified T error.

```
template<typename L, typename R>
static L AddObject(L lval, R rval){
    return lval + rval;
};
```

EDIT: Implemented solution code.

```
#include <string>
#include <sstream>

using namespace std;

class MathFuncs{
public:

    /.../

    template<typename L, typename R>
    static auto do_add(L lval, R rval, false_type){
        return lval + rval;
    }

    template<typename L, typename R>
    static string do_add(L lval, R rval, true_type){
        ostringstream oss;
        oss << lval << rval;
        return oss.str();
    }

    /*
     * Addition function.
     */
    template<typename L, typename R>
    static auto add(L lval, R rval){
        using dispatch_type = integral_constant<
            bool, 
            is_convertible<L, string>{}
            || is_convertible<R, string>{} >;
        return do_add(lval, rval, dispatch_type());
    }
};
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tag dispatch:

```
template<class A, class B>
auto do_add(A a, B b, std::false_type /*has_string*/) { return a + b; }

template<class A, class B>
std::string do_add(A a, B b, std::true_type /*has_string*/) {
   std::ostringstream oss; 
   oss << a << b; 
   return oss.str();
}

template<class A, class B>
auto add(A a, B b) {
    using dispatch_type = std::integral_constant<bool, 
                                   std::is_convertible<A, std::string>{}
                                || std::is_convertible<B, std::string>{}>;
    return do_add(a, b, dispatch_type());
}
```

Comment: I think it is the best option so far.

Comment: I like how this looks. It's easily understandable. Unfortunately, I need leave for a few hours. I'll test it when I'm back but for now I'll mark it as the solution. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 3):

Are you looking for

```
template<typename L, typename R>
static auto AddObject(L lval, R rval) -> decltype(lval + rval)
{
    return lval + rval;
};
```

Or, with C++14,

```
template<typename L, typename R>
static auto AddObject(L lval, R rval)
{
    return lval + rval;
};
```

This way the return type depends on whatever + is overloaded to be.

Comment: I'm gonna google and test what you are suggesting before answering.

Comment: Type deduction is pretty friendly, especially in C++14. The trick here will be in defining operator+ for the various combinations you'd like to add, e.g. std::string operator+(std::string lhs, double rhs) {/**/}

Comment: Oh so at that point I would have to overload the + operator to achieve that?

Answer (score 2):

EVERYTHING IS POSSIBLE WITH C++!

```
#include <type_traits>
#include <iostream>

template <class B>
typename std::enable_if < std::is_same<B,int>::value ||std::is_same<B,double>::value ,std::string   >::type
 add (std::string str , B b){
 return str + std::to_string(b);    
}

template <class B>
typename std::enable_if < std::is_same<B,int>::value ||std::is_same<B,double>::value  ,std::string   >::type
 add (B b, std::string str){
 return std::to_string(b)+ str ;    
}

template <class A , class B>
typename std::enable_if < (std::is_same<B,int>::value ||std::is_same<B,double>::value)&& (std::is_same<A,int>::value ||std::is_same<A,double>::value) , decltype(A()+B())  >::type
 add (B b, A a){
 return a+b;  
}

std::string add (std::string a , std::string b){
return a+b;    
} 

int main (void){
 std::cout << add("hi ", "there")<<"\n";
 std::cout << add ("hi there" , 3)<<"\n";
 std::cout << add (3 , "hi there")<<"\n";
 std::cout << add (2.2 , 1.1)<<"\n";
 std::cout << add (3.14 , 2)<<"\n";
 std::cout << add (4 , 2)<<"\n";
return 0;    
}
```

can be viewed here : http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/971d38aaebad2954

Comment: That's awesome! Thanks! I would only have one question. Would it be possible to make it more elegant? I'm gonna try to implement the version that @JonChesterfield suggested and if that won't work (with my knowledge) I'll use your suggestion.

Comment: amm, you can make it shorter if you play a bit with std::enable_if. to be honest, I don't see how Jon Chesterfield code  can actually work or be compiled. `decltype(std::string + int)` is not defined in any C++ standard way.

Answer (score 1):

C++ is a strongly typed language. If you want to do this kind of thing, you'll need to concisely specify the action you want to happen (add or concatenate) in the case of all parameter permutations and ensure you provide specialisations for each one. You'll also have to decide in the case of mixing strings with number types whether you want to convert the number to a string and treat both as text and concatenate.

for example:

```
template<>
static std::string AddObject<std::string, int>(string lval, int rval){
    std::ostringstream oss;
    oss << lval << rval;
    return oss.str();
};
```

You can certainly pass a function as a third parameter which will perform the 'action', though what benefit this will achieve, I'm not sure as the caller will have to chose and inject a method rather than leaving it encapsulated (which would seem to be the point of this template function)

From an overall design perspective, I would advise against this as a general case. The code which calls this will have to be equally concisely defined if you want to be absolutely clear what it will do. For example it will have to know that

```
AddObject( 1.0, 2.0 ) == 3.0
```

but

```
AddObject( "1.0", "2.0" ) == "1.02.0"
```

Depending on the source of your inputs, this may not be obvious.

Comment: So even with the use of templates this is not possible. In that case I will have to figure something out.

Comment: It is certainly possible, but probably much easier to achieve with a weakly typed language such as Javascript. One of the strengths of C++ is that it forces you to think in detail about what you are doing - and code accordingly - which usually leads to better quality code.

Comment: It's pretty funny that you mention JavaScript because this project is about making a compiler that translates JavaScript to machine code. I'm just testing the possibilities right now.

Comment: not that I don't agree completly, Javacript interperter is actually written in C/C++. that doesn't make C++ a dynamic ly - typed language, yet, you can do a lot of templates magic to imitate it. I think nothing is impossible in C++..