# C++ casting on the base of inheritance

Tags: c++, inheritance, casting

I have a method called addV that accepts two parameters.

`static auto addV(Value* lval, Value* rval)`

The Value type is a parent class that has childs like IntegerValue, StringValue, FloatValue, etc.
I never know which one of the child's will be send to addV. What would be the easiest and most elegant way of determining it and then adding it?

Example: lval = IntegerValue(10), rval = StringValue("Bruce"), return = StringValue("1Bruce")

Example: lval = StringValue("Tom"), rval = IntegerValue(2), return = StringValue("Tom2")

Example: lval = IntegerValue(1), rval = FloatValue(3.0), return = FloatValue(4.0)

I had a [previous post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30184928/c-return-type-equals-string-if-one-of-the-parameters-is-a-string) about doing exactly this but with primitive types.

Value class:

```
class Value {
protected:
    typedef enum{
        UndefinedType, 
        IntegerType, 
        ObjectType, 
        FloatType, 
        StringType, 
        BooleanType, 
        Last
    } DataType;

    public:
    virtual DataType returnType(){
        return UndefinedType;
    };
};
```

IntegerValue class:

```
class IntegerValue: public Value{
public:
    int32_t val;

    IntegerValue(int32_t val) : val(val){}

    DataType returnType(){
        return Value::IntegerType;
    };
};
```

FloatValue class:

```
class FloatValue: public Value{
public:
    float val;

    FloatValue(float val) : val(val) {}

    DataType returnType(){
        return Value::FloatType;
    };
};
```

StringValue class:

```
class StringValue: public Value{
public:
    string val;

    StringValue(string val) : val(val){}

    DataType returnType(){
        return Value::StringType;
    };
};
```

Comment: Looks like you want some kind of [multiple dispatch](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiple_dispatch#C.2B.2B). How you do this depends on what type information is available to you. Does your `Value` class have some kind of tag which could be used to identify the runtime type of an object, for example.

Comment: There are several different strategies for multiple dispatch like this. The trade-offs to consider are lookup time (linear vs logarithmic vs constant), and maintenance costs (is it more likely that you'll add new *types* in the future or new *functions*).

Comment: The given example is pretty much what I came up with without knowing it had a name. So that would be one of the only ways? The Value has a method called returnType that returns type from an enumerated list.

Comment: If you have a `returnType` function, you could switch on the result of that, `static_cast` the pointers to the correct type, then dispatch to specialised functions for those types.

Comment: I'm gonna try to play with that later. I also thought of trying enable_if (if it works without templates).

Comment: If you post the relevant parts of your code (`returnType` function with the type enum, `Value` class definitions), I'll write up an answer with the above suggestion.

Comment: @TartanLlama Ok, I just added the Value class in the post. Better code suggestions are always welcome of course.

Comment: Could you post the definitions of a few of the `*Type` objects as well; that way all the information needed will be in your question. Maybe just `IntegerType`, `FloatType` and `StringType`.

Comment: @TartanLlama I added all three off them to the post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would start with something like:

```
enum ValueTypesEnum {
   IntValueE = 0,
   FloatValueE = 1,
   StringValueE = 2
};


class Value {
public:
   virtual Value *create() = 0;
   virtual ValueTypesEnum getType() = 0;
   Value *max(Value *other) {
      if (getType() > other->getType()) {
         return this;
      } else {
         return other;
      }
   }
};


template <ValueTypesEnum MyType, class ValueT>
class ValueFactory:public Value {
public:
   ValueTypesEnum getType() {
      return MyType;
   }
   Value *create() {
      return new ValueT();
   }
};


class IntValue: public ValueFactory<IntValueE, IntValue> {
};

class FloatValue: public ValueFactory<FloatValueE, FloatValue> {
};

class StringValue: public ValueFactory<StringValueE, StringValue> {
};


Value *addV(Value *lval, Value *rval) {
   lval->max(rval)->create();
   // change to: return lval->max(rval)->create()->set(lval)->add(rval);
}
```

And then add the implementation of setting element in newly created value
by implementing the `set` and `add` virtual methods in the concrete classes.

Comment: This is the restructuring of the existing code and if I'm reading it correctly you are passing the enums to the classes? The addition class is going to be just one of the few that are going to use this structure. I'm gonna have to play with this later on.

Comment: @AdrianZ. actually I'm trying to make your concrete Value classes implementation independent from the enum value itself. It also suggest that the information which type should be created when given two Value types can be stored in the enum itself by the enum value rank. Only thing which was not inlcuded here is the implementation of the `set` and `add` values which actually would be the essense of making your application working.

Comment: Ok, I think I'm starting to understand how you are trying to do it. I'll come with results asap.

Comment: If I try to instantiate the class like this "Value* iv = new IntValue();" I get an error saying "./Values.h:39:16: error: no viable conversion from 'IntValue' to 'Value *' return ValueT();" I'm not sure what to do with that and what for is the create method? Also correct me if I'm wrong but this design has an add method in each and single value child class? While I just need 1 core add method.

Comment: You need to change line `return ValueT();` to `return new ValueT();` I'll make an edit in the answer...